# Subtasks in Rally

Tags: rally

I am a new user of Rally and would like to know if there is a way to create sub-tasks in Rally.  I am able to create tasks from within a user story, but not from within another task so it doesn't seem possible at first glance.

Answer (score 3):

In Rally there are no subtasks, and tasks cannot have child tasks.